# RE: Universal Wallet

Tags: blockchain, wallets, dapp-development, hd-wallets

I would like to create a multi currency wallet as a POC. I am currently able to make a wallet for Ethereum (Like balance, tx and all) but would like to create it for other as well (like Bitcoin).

I have looked into universal wallets available on the net namely:

```
Ethos
Jaxx
Atomic
Trust
```

and was thinking about making something along those lines

I would like to get answers to some questions

1. Just like using web3js for ETH, is there a way to do it for BTC? Same way like Infura, metamask etc etc for bitcoin exist or not?. If not, what are the alternatives? One is bitcore but I dont want to run a full node on my side

I am looking for directions and resources to start somewhere. Any advice would be useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi currency wallet (Universal wallet)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80070/multi-currency-wallet-universal-wallet)

Comment: This was the same question posted by me but it was closed and I was recommended to re-post the question but with focus on one type of problem. So thats why I have posted it again here.

Comment: This site is mostly about Ethereum related technologies so probably there better places to ask about Bitcoin and such. There are some libraries like bitcore-lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcore-lib or bitcoin-js https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcoinjs-lib. But bitcion has an account model that is different from Ethereum. My advice is to do it only to learn those technologies, writing a production ready wallet is a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs @ismael. You are correct. After digging a lot, I knew that this is a work heavy task, however I just want to make a POC and not the whole wallet and so I would try using the libs mentioned by you and start from there